# How to find a stochastic matrix by given complex eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

I know some general ways to build a matrix, which will have a given eigenvalues, but it will generally not be stochastic. For example, one can build canonical Jordan matrix by eigenvalues; yet it will be complex, if some of eigenvalues are complex, so it will not be stochastic. One can also use a generalization of it: a block-diagonal matrix, containing a block
[of this form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRIOZ.png) for each complex eigenvalue pair $\alpha \pm i \beta$; yet it will have negative elements, so it will not be stochastic as well.

How to gain a stochastic matrix by eigenvalues?

Comment: Eigen values of a stochastic matrix cannot be arbitrary. $1$  is an eigen value and $|\lambda| \leq 1$ for any eigen value $\lambda$.

Comment: Of course. But I ask for the case where one has a set of numbers, which correspond to all needed restrictions.